# window load not displaying correct else message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code with a .on click event and that works fine. However, if I change it to window load or doc ready, it displays ‘data in row’ even though there is no data. I am confused as to why it works on click event and not on load. Comments would be appreciated as this is driving me nuts. Many thanks

This works

```
$('#nirqst').on('click', 'tr', function () {
var table = $('#nirqst').DataTable();
 //get the current row
  var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  var col1 = currentRow.find(".dataTables_empty").html(); 
  if((col1)=='No data available in table') { 
    console.log(col1); 
    table.buttons().disable();
    } else {
    console.log('data in row');
    table.buttons().enable();
    }
});
```

This dosen’t

```
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
var table = $('#nirqst').DataTable();
 //get the current row
  var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
  var col1 = currentRow.find(".dataTables_empty").html(); 
  if((col1)=='No data available in table') { 
    console.log(col1); 
    table.buttons().disable();
    } else {
    console.log('data in row');
    table.buttons().enable();
    }
});
```

Generated html table

```
<table class="display stripe dataTable no-footer" id="nirqst" role="grid" aria-describedby="nirqst_info" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <!--        <caption>New Intake Requests</caption>-->
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th style="width: 4%;" class="hide_id sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="ID#">ID#</th>
      <th style="width: 4%;" class="hide_id sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nirqst" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="ID Number: activate to sort column ascending">ID Number</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nirqst" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label="Select-->: activate to sort column ascending">Select
        <!--<input type="checkbox" id="select_all" name="select_intake" />-->
      </th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nirqst" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 40px;" aria-label="Service: activate to sort column ascending">Service</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nirqst" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Activity: activate to sort column ascending">Activity</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nirqst" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Dept: activate to sort column ascending">Dept</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nirqst" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Company: activate to sort column ascending">Company</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nirqst" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 160px;" aria-label="Address: activate to sort column ascending">Address</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nirqst" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="User: activate to sort column ascending">User</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nirqst" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Box#: activate to sort column ascending">Box#</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nirqst" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Destroy Date: activate to sort column ascending">Destroy Date</th>
      <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="nirqst" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Request Date: activate to sort column ascending" aria-sort="descending">Request Date</th>
      <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 110px;" aria-label="Action">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td colspan="11" class="dataTables_empty" valign="top">No data available in table</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: did you try console logging `col1` inside window load event

Comment: @Jay it shows 'data in row' which is incorrect.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is $(this) which is referring to the window in the second case. you should try this

```
 $( window ).on( "load", function() {

  $('#nirqst tr').each(function () {
   var table = $('#nirqst').DataTable();
  var col1 = $(this).find(".dataTables_empty").html(); 

   if((col1)=='No data available in table') { 
     console.log(col1); 
      table.buttons().disable();
   } else {
      console.log('data in row');
     table.buttons().enable();
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. However, still getting the same problem.

Comment: because in the onclick event it is applied to all the tr and in the second case you have used closest which refers to first ancestor

Comment: What should second statement - load - be Mahesh? based on your comment. Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain your comment. Thanks

Comment: bro in second case this refers to whole window which obviously would have html element so it shows it has data and in the first case this refers to id nirqst which is table. the difference is in first case it refers to table in second case it refers to whole page

Comment: So how can I achieve the result when the page loads. I have tried a click event with trigger but still the same. Thanks

Comment: loop through all the tr in the table and find ".dataTables_empty". This would be working as you want

Comment: Do you have example of how I can do that please Mahesh. thanks

Comment: I have edited the answer please accept answer after all the efforts

Comment: I am gettinng SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

Comment: Unfortunately still getting the same error 'data in row'. I have tried without doc ready and with. Thanks

Comment: I shall post the generated html table. it may help.

Answer (score 0):

try, that should fire when the DOM is loaded.

```js
jQuery.ready(function(){
  console.log("DOM loaded");
});
```

Comment: Is there any particular place on the page I should place this as I have several doc ready statements on the page. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with place this? Do you mean where place the script tag that refers to the script? If yes than at the end of the body

Comment: it displays the message. Thanks